# Problema con php en vectores

Tags: php

Buenas, tengo un problema con php, es un formulario de vectores

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Ejercicio7.php - Vectores 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
if ( isset ($_POST['vec']));
{
    $vector =$_POST['vec'];
$n=count ($vector);
$suma=0;
echo "el vector tiene $n elementos <br>";
for ($i=0;$i<$n; $i++)
{
    echo $i = $vector [$i]. "<br>";
        $suma=$suma + $vector [$i];
    }
echo " la suma es ".$suma . "<br";
}

?>
<form action="ejercicio7.php" method= "get">
Numero de Elementos :
<input type="text" name="n" size="5">
<input type="submit" value="Aceptar">

</form>
<br>
<br>

<form action="ejercicio7.php" method="post">
<?php 
if (isset( $_GET['n']))
    $n=$_GET['n'];
else 
    $n=3;
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
    echo $i;
    echo "<input type= 'text' name='vec[]' size='10'>";
}

?>

<input type="submit">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me sale esto:

> Notice: Undefined index: vec in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerciciosPHP\ejercicio7.php on line 10

el vector tiene 0 elementos

Estoy repasando el código, pero no encuentro nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es sencillo, tienes un **;** (punto y coma) por demás en tu sentencia **if** en la línea 10.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el error esta a la hora de escribir el `if`.

```
if (condicion boleana) {

} else if (opcional) {

} else (opcional) {

}
```

Tu código bien escrito quedaría así:

```
if (isset ($_POST['vec'])) { //<-- Aquí estaba el error
    $vector =$_POST['vec'];
    $n=count ($vector);
    $suma=0;
    echo "el vector tiene". $n." elementos <br>";
    for ($i=0;$i<$n; $i++) 
    {
        echo $i = $vector [$i]. "<br>";
        $suma=$suma + $vector [$i];

    }
    echo " la suma es ".$suma . "<br";
}
```